# How to disable command+scroll zooming in openoffice calc

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, shortcuts, openoffice-calc

Is there anyway to have command+scroll in OSX do nothing instead of scrolling? I press the keyboard shortcut all the time and it throws my focus off. I have looked extensively in forums, but often the solution is for an older version of openoffice calc and I can't find the equivalent settings. And because it's a keyboard + mouse shortcut, I'm not able to disable it or remap it like I would through system preferences.

Could someone please help me figure out how to disable this shortcut?